# Shiny App Dashboard - 'Clear' button to remove imported file

Tags: r, shiny

I am planning to add a 'Clear' button to remove the imported file instead of restarting R session. But got an error message
**'Warning: Error in <-: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'** while importing the file within R studio.

UI.R:

```
  tabItem(tabName = "datexp",
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12,
                title = "Dataset for Exploration", status = "primary",
                solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE)
          ),
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 3,
              fluidRow(
                # Box to upload initial dataset.
                box(width = 12,
                    height = 500,
                    fileInput("file", "Select Dataset"),
                    actionButton("upload", "Import"),
                    actionButton('reset', 'Clear'),#Clear input dataset#
                    hr(),
```

......

Server.R:

```
    dataset <- reactive({
        file <- input$file
        if (is.null(file)){
          return(NULL)
        }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.sas7bdat')){
          dat <- setDT(read_sas(file$datapath))
        }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.xlsx')){
          dat <- setDT(read_excel(file$datapath))
        }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.csv')){
          dat <- setDT(read_csv(file$datapath))
        }
        dat
      })
      
      #Clear button
    observeEvent(input$upload, {
      req(input$reset)
    dataset$data <- NULL
  })
```

Comment: @akrun, rerun, thank you, pls take a look again.

Comment: May be you need `req(input$file)` at the top in `reactive`

Comment: @akrun, not working with same error, updated the question.

Comment: ok,  sorry, I cannot test your code as it is not complete.  My suggestion was just a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(haven)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 12,
          title = "Dataset for Exploration", status = "primary",
          solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE)
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3,
             fluidRow(
               # Box to upload initial dataset.
               box(width = 12,
                   height = 500,
                   fileInput("file", "Select Dataset"),
                   actionButton("upload", "Import"),
                   actionButton('reset', 'Clear'),#Clear input dataset#
                   hr()
               )
             )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(width = 12,
          DTOutput("t1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    file <- input$file
    if (is.null(file)){
      return(NULL)
    }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.sas7bdat')){
      dat <- setDT(haven::read_sas(file$datapath))
    }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.xlsx')){
      dat <- setDT(read_excel(file$datapath))
    }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.csv')){
      dat <- setDT(read_csv(file$datapath))
    }
    dat
  })
  
  mydf <- reactiveValues()
  ### load data
  observeEvent(input$upload, {
    mydf$data <- dataset()
  })
  ### Clear button
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    mydf$data <- NULL
  })
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT({mydf$data})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```